Cloud Run running Scrapyd abruptly terminating jobs without explanation
TL; DR: Service running in cloud run is abruptly killed, can't find any evidence to why.
Disclosure: I'm still familiarizing myself with GCP, so I might be missing something obvious.
I have a Cloud Run service running a scrapyd image. Scrapyd is a daemon service for deploying and running Scrapy spiders.
When running, the instances mount a GS bucket to persist storage. (Not sure if relevant)
Everything works, including project deployment. The problem is when a scrapy job is running: Sometimes the running job gets terminated. Without any explanation or apparent reason. For example the last 3 test jobs I executed, with the same project and same spider:

The first got terminated after 15min01sec
The second ran for over 16 HOURS and I manually terminated.
The third got terminated after 1hour 58min 03sec.

None of the hardware limits were hit, here are the metrics for the third job (between 1pm and 3pm)

In the GCP logs there is nothing that indicates why the process got terminated. No warning or errors, it doesn't even acknowledges that the job was killed. The scrapyd process is unaffected, and continues to run. The job logs terminate abruptly like this (last line of the log):
2024-07-26 17:59:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 409 pages (at 4 pages/min), scraped 3783 items (at 4 items/min)

If you are not familiar with scrapy:

When a job ends, it logs the job stats, including if it receives SIGTERM.
If scrapy receives SIGTERM more than once it forcefully shutdown, but logs it first. E.g:
2024-07-26 14:54:22 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGTERM twice, forcing unclean shutdown (from example 2)

Relevant notes

The job termination is so abrupt that I can only assume that the service got a SIGKILL. I don't know why though.
I couldn't reproduce this problem outside Cloud Run, which leads me to believe that this is somehow related to how Cloud Run operates.
If you notice in the image the "Container Instance Count" a second container is spun up and down three times during the job. I don't know why, or if it is in anyway related. A second container would only include the scrapyd service, and AFAIK wouldn't affect the job in anyway, as it is not distributed.

My questions are:

What could be the cause?
Where else can I look for insight beyond metrics and Logs Explorer?


Do you use Cloud Run Service (HTTP service) or Cloud Run Job? If Cloud RUn Service, can you share the code where you invoke it and run your scarpy process? I'm feeling what you are doing bad, just to be sure!

@guillaumeblaquiere Cloud run service. I deploy the project with scrapyd-client and run the job through a curl to the scrapyd schedule endpoint. There is no custom code in order to invoke the scrapy process.

I'm not a scrapyd user (and so not an expert) but I have the feeling that the client runs a job in the background (it returns a job ID)
If my understanding is correct, the request flow is the following:

The invoker calls Cloud Run endpoint
The cloud run service calls Scapyd client -> That spawns a job in the background
The Cloud Run service returns a HTTP code to the invoker.
The job continues in the background


If this is correct, your 15 minutes lifetime is normal. As you can see in the Cloud Run service instance lifecycle documentation, the Cloud Run instance is killed after 15 minutes of inactivity (idle), i.e. 15 minutes without receiving any request.
The behavior here is pretty normal! So why the other timeout?
Because the Cloud Run instance is killed after 15 minutes of inactivity, you should have regularly invoked the existing instance, maybe for monitoring it or whatever. It's not random!

In addition to termination, you should get another issue: slowness! Indeed, while your instance is outside any request context, the CPU is throttled (about 2 or 3% of the CPU is available for idle instance, to keep connection (like database connection) alive, but no more).
I don't know if you notice slow processing but it's one of other side effect.

Since you are performing a batch job, you should use a batch service, like Cloud Batch or, better, Cloud Run Job. You should have to update your container, but the advantage is you no longer need a webserver, you could use the scrapy CLI to start it, and use the container override (with Cloud Run Job) to pass parameters.
